# VBA filter to hide fdates in the past not working

Tags: vba, date, filter

[image][image]This code seems to filter all dates

```
Sub AdDate()

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableAOrders").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & Date    
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

All I want filtered are all dates in the past.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that if you want to include today, change `">"` to `">="`.

Comment: That still hides all rows

Comment: Both suggestions so far from BigBen and Nathan_Sav do not work

Comment: Maybe share a screenshot of your table? Are the dates actually dates or *text-that-looks-like-a-date*?

Comment: does this work?  `">" & format(date,"dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: They are dates:

Comment: Can't reproduce your error - as requested, a screenshot would help.

Comment: You should be able to get 90% of the code you need with the macro recorder - you might have to replace today's date with `Date`, but otherwise you'll have what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. Looks like dates. Can you record a macro while manually adding a date filter to keep dates after or equal to today, and then inspect the recorded code?

Comment: Also remove the `On Error Resume Next` - does the code throw any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You bring dates starting from today; in fact Date is not used that way.

For the past dates your filter must be:

Criteria1:="<" & Now()

Comment: Didn't work, I'm beginning to think the problem is my table not VBA

Comment: Everyone asked you to provide a screenshot because Excel is "dumb" when it comes to dates. Make sure the col containing dates is formated as "Date" otherwise Excel treats the data as a simple text (string).

Comment: Photos attached